# C function insert item in list

Tags: c, list

I have to create a list where each node contains the information of a game. Data are acquired by keyboard. So I have to create an insert function(inserisciTestaLista) in the list,but when I run the program stops. I have no compilation errors. 
This's output:

```
...\Debug\progetto1.exe (processo 7356) terminato. Codice restituito: -1073741819.
Premere un tasto qualsiasi per chiudere questa finestra...
```

this's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_partita {
    char team1[32], team2[32];
    int set1, set2;
    char data[11];
}t_partita;

typedef struct nodo {
    t_partita info;
    struct nodo  *next;
}t_nodo, *lista;

void inserisciTestaLista(lista *L, t_partita partita) {
    lista aux;
    aux = (lista)malloc(sizeof(t_nodo));
    if (aux == NULL)
        exit(1);
    aux->info = partita;
    aux->next = *L;
    *L = aux;

}


int main() {
    int scelta = 0;
    lista L = NULL;
    t_partita  partita;

    do {
        printf("*****************MENU**************\n");
        printf("0. ESCI\n");
        printf("1. inserisci partita\n");
        printf("2. stampa lista\n");
        scanf("%d", &scelta);
        switch (scelta) {
        case 1: {
            printf("Inserisci team 1: ");
            scanf("%s", partita.team1);
            printf("Inserisci team 2: ");
            scanf("%s", partita.team2);
            printf("Inserisci punteggio (esempio 3-1): ");
            scanf("%d%d", &partita.set1, &partita.set2);
            printf("Inserisci data (esempio 2020-01-01): ");
            scanf("%s", partita.data);

            inserisciTestaLista(L, partita);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {

            break;
        }
        }
    } while (scelta != 0);

}
```

Comment: Please place your program output as text, not as an image, inside the question itself. [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Pro tip: Don't hide pointer types in type aliases. There are two reasons to do that otherwise-shunned practice (black-box "handle" APIs and callback function prototyping) and this is neither of those. It actually makes the code *harder*, not easier, to read and maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the memory address from the list in line 49.

```
  inserisciTestaLista(&L, partita);
```